# Will a 6' circumference tomato cage work?

Tags: tomatoes, support

In my past experience with growing industrial sized tomato plants I need oversized tomato cages, so I use concrete mesh to grow my tomatoes, but I cut some a little too long, so now I have 2 tomato cages that have a circumference of 6'. Will these work to support tomatoes? For the type of tomato cage think of the ones made out of concrete mesh.

parts of a circle
[image: parts of a circle]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. I would in any case put two/three poles (or more if you are in a windy/stormy place). For the weight, it is not a problem.

I just do no like that you cannot enter in the center, and you will (I think) have difficult to reach it with hands, but it depends on the mesh type.

In my opinion, linear is often much better, for space efficiency, for watering.

Personally, I do no like cages for tomatoes. I prefer a pole (with maybe some extra bamboo): you can move branches easily, without breaking.

Comment: I have the watering problem solved by the creek about 200 feet away, and just a little lower.

Comment: Two sturdy polls work in windy areas if you snug them up to the diameter.

Comment: what about burying it into woodchips in order to have the entire base of the ring be the grounding points?

Comment: I do not understand the subject. Do you mean using just mash instead of poles? This is engineering. Try it. Just push and pull (before to plant tomatoes), and you will see it is enough fix. Sticks go deeper, where the soil is more solid and there is more pressure. But it all depends on the surface toward soil, the type of soil, and the amount of water. I'm not a geologist, so I have only my experience on my garden. Try and learn and fix. After storms I still need to fix some stuffs.